# I can see live app on secured port 443 red5pro

Tags: red5

I prepared server ubuntu like from docs. I created SSL cert to my domin and i have open required ports. I installed red5pro in to `/usr/local/red5pro/` and server fine. When i will go to http://example.com:5080/ i can see home page red5pro and is ok. But when i click on broadcast i have a info: `No suitable Publisher found. WebRTC & Flash not supported.` Ok, maybe because is http not https. I decided create test index page in to `/var/www/test/index.html` and i have basic configuration like:

```
var config = {
          protocol: 'wss',
          host: 'example.com',
          port: 443,
          app: 'live',
          streamName: 'abccaccaa',
          rtcConfiguration: {
            iceServers: [{urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'}],
            iceCandidatePoolSize: 2,
            bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle'
          } // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection#RTCConfiguration_dictionary
        };
```

And now when i try broadcast have an info: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/live/?id=abccaccaa' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Looks like have no `example.com/live` and cant figure out what is wrong :( since 2 days. Maybe someone could give me an advice ? Or alternative on other application than red5pro

Comment: Some context would help -- what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to install red5pro server and testing standard stream but i can't connect when server is online with ssl

Comment: example.com is a test domain, I doubt your SSL cert allowed that domain and if it did it wont resolve via DNS. You need a real domain that you own with the associated SSL cert to use https/wss features. In addition, you do not need SSL for subscribe on WebRTC nor RTMP/Flash; you only need it for WebRTC publish. I suggest that you review the HTML SDK docs for the correct way to utilize the server.